# GT data_color bins based on column values

Tags: r, gt

Im trying to create 3 bins based on the last 4 columns so that way I do not have to create 30 data_color and manually import the percentile groups, but everything ive tried so far just results in yellow for all the textboxes, im not sure how to use postional arguments for the column to assign the bin values

the below code is the desired output with manually entering the values for the bins as percentil10 through percentile90

```
gt(
  tribble(~key,~linetext,~`2021:4`,~`2022:1`,~`2022:2`,~`2022:3`,~"R4 Quarters",~"Volume Qtr",~"90th PCTL",~"75th PCTL", ~"50th PCTL",~"10th PCTL"
          ,"doesnt matter","doesnt matter",100.00,100.00,85.71,100.00,94.12,91.94,100,97.57,93.63,80.97)
) %>%
  data_color(
    rows = c(1),
    columns = c(3,4,5,6,7),
    method = "bin",
    fn = scales::col_bin(tribble(~percentile10,~percentile50,~percentile75,~percentile90
                                 ,80.97,93.63,97.57,100),
                         palette = c("#ffc0cb","#ffff00","#90ee90"),
                         reverse = FALSE,
                         domain = NULL),
    na_color = "white"
  )
```